# How to prove there is no finite-dimensional feature space for Gaussian RBF kernel?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick

How to prove that for the radial basis function $k(x, y) = \exp(-\frac{||x-y||^2)}{2\sigma^2})$ there is no finite-dimensional feature space $H$ such that for some $\Phi: \text{R}^n \to H$ we have $k(x, y) = \langle \Phi(x), \Phi(y)\rangle$?

Comment: Is this question more appropriate for Mathematics?

Comment: One possible plan of attack would be to exhibit a subspace of $H$ that is not closed.

Comment: @Nick Alger: maybe this helps: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80398/svm-in%EF%AC%81nite-dimensional-feature-space/168309#168309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that Gaussian RBF kernel $k(x, y)$ is defined on domain $X \times X$ where $X$ contains an infinite number of vectors. One can prove ([Gaussian Kernels, Why are they full rank?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130554/gaussian-kernels-why-are-they-full-rank)) that for any set of distinct vectors $x_1, ..., x_m \in X$ matrix $(k(x_i, x_j))_{m \times m}$ is not singular, which means that vectors $\mathrm\Phi(x_1), ..., \mathrm\Phi(x_m)$ are linearly independent. Thus, a feature space $H$ for the kernel $k$ cannot have a finite number of dimensions.

Comment: Here you find a more 'intuitive' explanation that the $\Phi$ can map onto a spave of dimension equal to the size of the training sample, even for an infinite training sample: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80398/svm-in%EF%AC%81nite-dimensional-feature-space/168309#168309

Answer (score 11):

The [Moore-Aronszajn theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space#Moore-Aronszajn_theorem) guarantees that a symmetric positive definite kernel is associated to a unique reproducing kernel Hilbert space. (Note that while the RKHS is unique, the mapping itself is not.)

Therefore, your question can be answered by exhibiting an infinite-dimensional RKHS corresponding to the Gaussian kernel (or RBF). You can find an in-depth study of this in "[An explicit description of the reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces of Gaussian RBF kernels](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1705021)", Steinwart et al.